# Launch angle affecting the splash height of a ball

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, fluid-dynamics, projectile, home-experiment

I need to do an experiment about the launch angle of a ball affecting its splash height. I have no idea if it's feasible or not, and I can't find anything similar online. Can anyone help? My set up is below, please ignore the position of the camera.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the vertical velocity of the ball as it reaches the same height on the right hand side. By symmetry, this will be the vertical velocity (and horizontal) component of the projectile just as it leaves the cannon. What exactly do you want to calculate or need to know?

Comment: For now, I just need to know if this experiment will work. Because this is what I came up with for one of my graded components. I'm also trying to find out what type of ball to use.

Comment: What do you mean? You need to know what will work?

Comment: I need to know if the experiment will work, cus I'm afraid that the splash heights will all be the same if I use a ball.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can model the situation crudely using simple energy conservation. Work out the total speed of the ball as it hits the water's surface and calculate its kinetic energy. Assume a mass $m_\text{water}$ of the water rises above the surface due to the splash and write down the expression for its gravitational potential energy. Equate the two energies and solve for $h$, the height above the water's surface.

(Note: you might need to settle on a reasonable value of $m_\text{water}$ first.)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't need to do that. I just need to know if it will work or not, and also the type of ball to use